# How to make long images fit in the CollapsibleToolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am tying to add image in a `Fragment` with image at the top and parallax effect when scrolled down. I tried doing this using Collapsible Toolbar, but image is not filling up the Collapsible Toolbar, and parallax is not working.

I want something like this
[image]

But this is what I achieved till now.

[image: But this is what I achieved till now.]

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/drawerlayout1">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="70dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/actionbarlayout"
        android:layout_height="207dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/CollapsingToolbarLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/details_Image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/new_order"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/download"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ic_file_download_white_36dp"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/favourite"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">


                                <ImageButton
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/zoom"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ic_zoom_out_map_white_36dp"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    />

                            </RelativeLayout>



                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
                            android:text="keckwcbjbewbcbcbcwjbejwkbcwkbcbwjc"

                            />



                    </ScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/fullimage"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="70dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="207dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/CollapsingToolbarLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/details_Image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/new_order"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/download"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ic_file_download_white_36dp"
                                    android:background="@null" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/favourite"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">


                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/zoom"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ic_zoom_out_map_white_36dp"
                                    android:background="@null" />

                            </RelativeLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="keckwcbjbewbcbcbcwjbejwkbcwkbcbwjc"

                            />


                    </ScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Replace your code with this.

Comment: Are you change collapsing toolbar layout height width to match parent?

Comment: And charge android: scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Tried that, not working. I think image is too long for that collapsible toolbar.

Is there another way to place an ImageView with parallax effect wen scrolled?